# Regular Expression in Java which returns false if any of the Characters other than "N","E","W","S" is found

Tags: java, regex

I have written a Java Program for the regular expression. 
I am looking for regular expression which actually returns me false if any of the Characters other than these  "N","E","W","S"    found in the text.
I have used this        Pattern.matches("[^NWES]", str) in my program it didn't worked.

Comment: Just add a quantifier. `+` or `*`, your choice. And use `str.matches(regex)`, it's shorter and more idiomatic.

Comment: "It didn't worked" (sic) is _not_ a good bug report. Exactly _how_ did it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a quantifier with your Regex: -

```
return Pattern.matches("[NWES]+", str);
```

Comment: Ummm... I guess you need a `!` in front of that ;)

Comment: @m.buettner.. Yeah. didn't notice that it should return false.

Comment: Come to think about it, I guess the double negation is actually a bit counter-intuitive. Maybe it's best to just search for `[NWES]+`.

Comment: @m.buettner. Yeah. got lost in there in the question for a while.

Comment: @m.buettner You would need anchors `^` and `$` in this case.

Comment: @msandiford.. Of course he meant `match`, when he said `search`.

Comment: ...and now replace `if (boolExpr) return true` with `return boolExpr` :)

Comment: @msandiford what Rohit Jain said ;)

Comment: I think m.buettner is correct, I tried with Rohit solution added with m.buettner it worked.

Comment: @Kumar.. Yeah, this is more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking to match valid points of the compass. If so, it's not a simple as your question suggests to do properly.

A valid compass point is comprised of `NSEW` sure, but:

- has at most two different letters
- `N` and `S` never both appear
- `E` and `W` never both appear
- if `E` or `W` appear twice, they are first and last with either `N` and `S` in the middle
- for two-letter points, N`and`S`appear before`E`and`W`
- etc

Now this *could* be expressed as a regex, but at this point it would be simpler, easy and more useful to put the compass points in an `enum` and use [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to validate the input (which throws a IllegalArgumentException if the input is invalid)